# ( displaying properly but not uploading)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
     for (File file : file_count) {
     String name=file.getName();
     System.out.println("E:\\mobile data\\Manikandan\\test"+name);
     
    WebElement upload=driver.findElement(By.id("files"));
    upload.sendKeys("E:\\mobile data\\Manikandan\\test"+name);
    
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

E:\mobile data\Manikandan\test1.JPG
**ERROR CODE:
FAILED: facebooklogi
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: File not found : E:\mobile data\Manikandan\test1.JPG**

Answer (score 0):

If your file is **locally** you should use

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
element = driver.find_element_by_id("fileUpload")
element.send_keys("C:\myfile.txt")
```

otherwise using **remoteWebDriver**

```
driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.id("myfile"));
upload.sendKeys("/Users/sso/the/local/path/to/darkbulb.jpg");
```

[Uploading files using Webdriver](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-can-i-work-with-file-uploads-during-a-webdriver-test)